# ASP.NET MVC Set property of model during form send

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 submit buttons on ASP.NET MVC form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicationDriverForm", "ApplicationDriver", routeValues: new { CompanyUniqueString = Model.CompanyUniqueString }, method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id="appForm1", name="appForm1" }))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" value="Save - but don't send" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" name="btnSend" id="btnSend" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to set different parameters for one of model property. I try to do it using the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('btnSave').on('click', function () {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('input[id=@Html.IdFor(model=>model.Status)]').val('@Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverStatusStrings.Processing');
            if ($(this).valid())
                $('#appForm1').submit();
        });

        $('btnSend').on('click', function () {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('input[id=@Html.IdFor(model=>model.Status)]').val('@Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverStatusStrings.Submit');
            if ($(this).valid())
                $('#appForm1').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

but nothing happened, these functions are not call at all, form is sending with empty Status property. Why?

Comment: Your selectors are incorrect - `$('#btnSave')` and `$('#btnSend')` (the leading `#` identifies an element by is `id` attribute)

Comment: Note also `if ($(this).valid())` makes no sense (`$(this)` is the submit button, not the form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `ev.preventDefault()`, but `ev` is undefined, because your handler functions don't take the event as a parameter. Change it to:

```
$('btnSave').on('click', function (ev) {
```

And

```
$('btnSend').on('click', function (ev) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the input type to `button` instead of `submit` if you wish to prevent the form submission, do work and then submit.

You are also missing a '#' before your JQuery id selectors e.g. should be '`#btnSave`'.

Comment: This is just wrong. It may "fix" the problem, but it does it by breaking the default functionality of having an actual submit button.